# Output internal reg to a .txt in Verilog

Tags: verilog, testbench

I would like to write an internal reg to a txt file.

I have tried something like:

```
    f = $fopen("conv2_tb_output.txt","w");
    $fmonitor(f, value=%d\n", mat_out);
    $fclose(f);
```

But since mat_out is an internal reg, I got an error:  is not declared.

Does anyone body know how to write internal regs to a txt file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're trying to access a register inside a module from a testbench that instantiates that module.  In this case, I think what you need to do is use a hierarchical reference.  Instead of using mat_out, use module_instance_name.mat_out where module_instance_name is the name of the instance of the module that contains mat_out.

Comment: That's it. Now I don't get any error, but conv2_tb_output.txt does not contain anything. I have to say that mat_out is a matrix. https://www.edaplayground.com/x/6G7h#

Comment: Try it with a simple integer and see if that works.  Or try accessing a single element of the matrix.  You may need to do a bit more work to print out a whole matrix (i.e. you may need to use a for loop and iterate over it).

Comment: Also, maybe try closing the file at the end of the testbench instead of immediately after opening it.

Comment: It's really weird, but, if after $fmonitor(f, "time=%5d, valor=%d\n", $time, uut.mat_out); I write anything like: $fmonitor(f, "time=%5d, valor=%d\n", $time, uut.mat_out); fdsfdsfdfsd. The simulation fails but the txt file contains mat_out!!! Can you explain that? lol